# Bing Maps API v7 limit by bounds

Tags: javascript, maps, bing-maps, bing-api

So I'm trying to use the Search Module of the Bing Maps AJAX API (v7), and I've noticed that [in the Interactive SDK for it](http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#SearchModule4) you can pass in a property called `bounds` which you give a bounding box to search within. The example simply uses the map's current bounding box so theoretically, if you zoom in, a new search should simply show you results within your zoomed in area, right?

Well here's the issue: Add the following code at the end of the example code in the Interactive SDK:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'viewchange', searchRequest);
```

What this *should* do is every time you move around the map or zoom in or out, it should fire a new search with the new bounding area of the map... I say this because of the line that looks like this: `bounds: map.getBounds(),`. What actually happens is that it bounces back to where it was initially before zooming.

Call me crazy, but is the `bounds` property just being completely ignored? Does anyone know how to limit the search results to the currently visible map area?

Lastly: Is it just me, or are the API docs for V7 rather incomplete? I've managed to find a few things by inspecting stuff in the Chrome console that doesn't appear in the API docs.

*Update:* This is what my call to the search function looks like:

```
searchManager.search({
    bounds: map.getBounds(),
    callback: searchSuccess,
    count: 20,
    entityType:"Business",
    errorCallback: searchFail,
    startIndex: 0,
    userData: userData,
    what: what,
    where: search
});
```

Comment: The doc. is quite complete, but keep in mind when searching for class functionality that you want to make sure you are looking at the correct version of the map class.  For instance, version 6.0 / 7.0 map class function quite similar, but their syntax and class paths are quite different.

Comment: I'm definitely looking at v7.0 (see the Interactive SDK link in my OP), in fact... the example I provided above is within the Interactive SDK so there's nothing to do with v7.0 in there.

Comment: Sorry Remy I should have been more specific! I had meant to say MSDN has a quite complete set of documentation for the two, as well as migrating.  I used to to upgrade from 6.0 to 7.0 and it was a great help! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877180.aspx

Comment: I tried this out, hooking up viewchangeend event instead of viewchange in case the map didn't have time to update its bounds correctly.   Verified that the bounds passed into the search does get updated properly, but the returned results are always the same.  This could be a caching issue or some other thing, but I don't have the time/motivation to dig further ;-)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look anyway. I'll give that `viewchangeend` a try and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

I have not personally used on view changed as I'm not sure that was available when I migrated from 6.0.

I'll share an alternative route I went that gets the trick done.

My search functionality also puts a Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin exactly where the user searched ("You are here!").

I then I create a boundary from the pushpin:

```
var viewBoundaries = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(pushpin.getLocation());
```

Then set the Map.setView properties for bounds. (Aswell as zoom in my case)

```
map.setView({ bounds: viewBoundaries });
map.setView({ zoom: 10 });
```

If you are not using a pushpin, you can simply create the view boundary from the location class.

[MSDN Location Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427612.aspx)

Comment: This is in fact how I'm showing all the pins on my map. The problem that I'm having is that even though I'm passing in the `bounds` property (which is used in the Interactive SDK) when I call the `searchManager.search` function, it's not searching within those boundaries. I'll update my OP with how my call to the search looks.

Comment: Remy sorry, I just noticed your comment on because someone up vote. Did you figure this out? If not, what is the "bounds" you are trying to search? A polygon on the map, view bounds etc.?